# Java Postgresql How to generate primary key automatically

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I woudlike to generate automatically a new id (primary key) when I use `INSERT INTO` :

```
    String id = "1";
    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE (id) VALUES(?)");
    prep.setString(1, id); // generate new id 
    prep.executeUpdate();
```

Actually I set 1 to my `id` but if I want to generate more `INSERT INTO` How can I INSERT INTO new value with new id ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement) Or this? [Generate Auto ID in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763115/generate-auto-id-in-postgresql)

Comment: Related: [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc) If you want to generate an id, you shouldn't specify it in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an identity column:

```sql
create table foo 
(
  id integer primary key generated always as identity, 
  some_column text, 
  ... 
)
```

Then use `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`

```java
int id = -1;
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE (some_column) VALUES(?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
prep.setString(1, "some value");
prep.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = prep.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
  id = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: perfect ! Thank you ! (you just forget ')' after rs.next())